# Mysql keyword in command executed from a shell script

Tags: mysql, shell

I already know that in order to make Mysql understands a keyword as a column name we should add back ticks.

I am trying to execute this command from a shell script

```
echo "ALTER TABLE   partners.partners CHANGE COLUMN `name` `client_name` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL" | $MYSQL
```

Where `$MYSQL` is my databse connection command (which works fine for other commands).

What I am trying to do is rename the colomn named `name` to `client_name` but I have got this error :

```
 ./test_script.sh: 1: ./test_script.sh: name: not found
```

If I log to mysql console , execute the same thing , It works perfectly

Any one run into this problem before ?

Comment: Try escaping the backticks (IE: \\`name\\`). I think the backticks are being evaluated as shell commands - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes to avoid interpretation of back-tick or ` which is otherwise used for command substitution:

```
$MYSQL -e 'ALTER TABLE partners.partners CHANGE COLUMN `name` `client_name` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL'
```

Comment: That should've been my first reflex ! It is exactly that